# I can't use "jsbin" code localy , JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all this is the code   [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/utakef/258/edit)

The code is used to show and hide a DIV using one button  when i run it locally it does not work !! , this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//fb.me/react-with-addons-0.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
#login_Box_Div{
  background:#999;
  display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$('#buttonLogin').click(function(){
   $('#login_Box_Div').toggle();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<h3> <a href= "#">Pictio  </a> <button id="buttonLogin">LogIn</button></h3>

  <div id = "login_Box_Div"> 
        <form name = "myform" > 
            <input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "Username"  />
            <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder= "Password" />
            <input type = "submit" id = "submitLogin" />
        </form>

</div>






  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot document.ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers read from top to bottom.  When your jQuery executes, the browser has not found the element yet, so nothing happens.  Move your `<script>` tags to the bottom of the page (right before the body ending tag).  Alternatively, you could wrap your jQuery code in [`$(document).ready(`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), which delays execution until the entire page has been read.

Comment: i m sorry i am not a  JQuery developer -_-

Answer (score 0):

Replace this -

```
<script>
$('#buttonLogin').click(function(){
   $('#login_Box_Div').toggle();
});
</script>
```

with this -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // tells jquery that the document is ready to whirl
    $('#buttonLogin').click(function(){
       $('#login_Box_Div').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

The code is placed into a document ready handler which essentially lets jQuery know that all of the elements are in the document. Once they are in the document they can be acted upon by the code that you wrote. Without this handler the code runs without regard for whether the element exists or not and that may cause, as you have seen, some problems.

Comment: sorry , but can you explain what is the difference ?